# How to translate this .htaccess line to web.config for IIS?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Here's my .htaccess rule that I confirm works:

`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/foo/products products.aspx?product_id=${product_map:$1} [NC, L]`

What it does is uses the `product_map.txt` file to map between the product_id (query string) and the product name.  For example let's say tools ID is 1.  The following 2 would be equivalent/rewritten:

```
site.com/tools/foo/products
site.com/products.aspx?product_id=1
```

When using IIS's rule import, this turns into the following:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/foo/products" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="products.aspx?product_id={product_map:{R:1}}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

However it is saying the expression `products.aspx?product_id={product_map:{R:1}} is not valid`, is there any way to get this to work in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rewrite map in IIS. The work of it is same as product_map.txt, mapping the product name to product id.

```
 <rewrite>
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="product_map">
                <add key="tools" value="1" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule">
                <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/foo/products" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{product_map:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="products.aspx?product_id={C:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

[image]